# Учёт сотых долей секунды в таймере обратного отсчёта времени

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо сделать отсчёт заданного количества секунд при клике на кнопку.
Нужно отсчитать 20 секунд, но также должны считаться сотые доли секунды.

Код блока таймера:

```
<div class="timer">00:<span class="seconds">20</span>:<span class="centisecond">00</span></div>
```

Для секунд я сделал так:

```
function timer() {

        var seconds = 20;

        var seconds_timer_id = setInterval(function() {
            if (seconds > 0) {
                seconds --;
                if (seconds < 10) {
                    seconds = "0" + seconds;
                }
                $(".seconds").text(seconds);
            } else {
                clearInterval(seconds_timer_id);    
            }
        }, 1000);

    }
```

А как сделать сотые доли секунды?

Comment: вместо 1000 напишите 10, это и есть сотая часть секунды

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
function timer() {
  var msecond = 2000;

  var seconds_timer_id = setInterval(function() {
    seconds = Math.floor(msecond/100);
    centisecond = Math.floor(msecond - seconds*100);
    if (msecond >= 0) {
      msecond --;
      if (centisecond < 10) {
        centisecond = "0" + centisecond;
      }
      $(".centisecond").text(centisecond);

      if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
      }
      $(".seconds").text(seconds);
    } else {
      clearInterval(seconds_timer_id);    
    }
  }, 10);
}
```